# How to trigger the parent element when firing an event?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, event-handling

I want to console log the button every time the button is clicked but if I click any child element within the button, the child gets printed instead which is not I want. How do I make sure the element which has the event listener is printed?

```
 const onCrossClick = (e) => {
   console.log(e.target);
 };
```

```
<button
  className="delete-button"
  onClick={onCrossClick}
>
  <i className="fas fa-times-circle fa-2x"></i>
</button>
```

Comment: What do you need the element that has the event listener for? That will help provide an answer to your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const onCrossClick = (e) => {
   console.log(e.currentTarget);
};

<button
  className="delete-button"
  onClick={onCrossClick}>    
     <i className="fas fa-times-circle fa-2x"></i>
</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `closest()`.

```js
const onCrossClick = (e) => {
   console.log(e.target.closest("button"));
};
```